# Selenium Python - sending keys from an array to a different array starting from index 2

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm doing some UI testing and ran into an issue

All of the headers are just plain text and the `textboxes` are elements with a placeholder to send keys in.
The only way to locate them is by CLASS_NAME so I can not distinguish from the subject and desc which I have no interest in to the picks, therefore, I need to create an array based on the `CLASSNAME` all 5 `textboxes` have in common and insert the values as written below.

Voting subject

-------textbox1-------

Voting description

----textbox2-----

VotingPick1

-----textbox3----

VotingPick2

-----------textbox4---------

VotingPick3

-----textbox5----

Example:

````
emptyOptions = ['textbox1', 'textbox2', 'textbox3', 'textbox4', 'textbox5']

votingOptions = ['YES', 'NO', 'IDK' ]
i wish to start the emptyOptions array from index 2 so textbox3 will get YES
textbox4 will get NO and textbot5 will get IDK



```
    for option in votingOptions:
        emptyOptions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'formCTRL')
        i = 10
           for o in emptyOptions:
              o.send_keys(option)
        i += 1

    i += 1
````

```
this isn't the full code I've tried. I messed it up and some parts are missing but I don't think even then it would make this work.
```

Comment: Hi, your question is very confusing. You should maybe explain a little bit more or rewrite your question because its not very clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi again, i'm sorry but it is still confusing. Maybe you could provide what would be exactly in the emptyOptions after getting the return from `driver.fine_elements` maybe that will make it a bit more clear. Also as the answer below said. You can use my_list[2:] in general (python) to start an array from the 3 index and ignore the first 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're expanation is a bit confusing but as far as I understood this should work :

```py
emptyOptions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'formCTRL')
for option,form in zip(votingOptions, emptyOptions[1:]):
    form.send_keys(option)
```

`emptyOptions[1:]` means you start the list from index 1, so you ignore the two first elements
`zip(list_a,list_b)` allows you to loop simultaneously on both list

Comment: didnt work for me. i have edited my post. maybe my intentions are more clear now

Comment: Hey little hint. If he want to start from the 3rd item he needs [2:]. its always [included_from:excluded_till]. So 0 and 1 are not included. 2 is and then the rest till we have no end defined.